# Curl выводит значение в браузере

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

```
        $ch2 = curl_init($url2);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER ,array(
        "Authorization: $token_type $access_token",
        'Cache-Control: no-cache'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        $response2 = curl_exec($ch2);

        curl_close($ch2);
```

Выводит в браузер

[image: Вывод в браузере]

Без всякого echo и т.п

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В другом контексте ($ch, а не $ch2) для вызова функций curl_setopt

Comment: Я вижу, что этот код делает запрос, но ничего не выводит.
Проверьте весь код, пожалуйста. Так же где-то `$ch`, где-то `$ch2` переменная используется, что странно. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` - за счет этого в output ничего не должно идти

Comment: Спасибо! Глаза замылились! ch2

Comment: Если считаете, что именно этот кусок кода выводи данные, то включите буферизацию вывода https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php на этом блоке кода https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-end-clean.php. Если текст перестанет появляться, то вы правы. Но я сильно сомневаюсь в таком исходе. Текст выводится где-то в другом месте